# Is there is a difference between two constructs

Tags: c++, string, constructor

If there is a difference between two constructs
I would like to know

```
std::string name = std::string("Eugene");
```

and

```
std::string name = "Eugene";
```

Comment: Assuming C++17 or later:  **no**, they are the same except for more typing in the first case.

Comment: that is, the compiler, in the absence of an explicit call to std::string(), will call it for me?

Comment: `std::string name { "Eugene" };` is even shorter. Maybe not shorter but more idiomatic.

Comment: [Some good reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) on the topic. And [here's some good viewing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs).

Comment: @MaskOryle in `std::string name = "Eugene";` this is an explicit call to the constructor of the string.

Comment: @bolov "Eugene" - is this an explicit constructor call?

Comment: @MaskOryle no. But this is: `std::string name = "Eugene";` it might look like an assignment, but it's not. It's a constructor call.

Comment: Before C++17, there is a semantic difference. The first uses `std::string("Eugene")` to construct a temporary `std::string` using the literal `"Eugene"`, a copy constructor to construct `name` from that temporary, and the temporary then ceases to exist. In the second, name is constructed directly from the literal `"Eugene"`.  The wrinkle is that the implementation is explicitly *permitted but not required* to elide the temporary (i.e. never create it) and, for implementations which do that, the two cases are equivalent.  In C++17, the elision became mandatory, so the two cases are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### C++11

First lets consider the statement:

```
std::string name = std::string("Eugene");
```

For the above shown statement there are 2 possibilities in C++11.

1. A **temporary object** of type `std::string` is created using `"Eugene"` on the right hand side. Then, the copy/move constructor of `std::string` is used to construct the object named `name`.
2. In C++11, there is [**non-mandatory copy elision**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which means that implementations are allowed to elide the temporary on the right hand side. This means **instead of** creating a temporary on the right hand side and then using a copy/move constructor to construct `name`, implementations can just directly construct `name` from `"Eugene"`.

Now lets consider the statement:

```
std::string name = "Eugene"; //this is initialization
```

In the above statement, an object named `name` is constructed using the **string literal** and a suitable `std::string`'s constructor.

So, the answer to your question in C++11 is that there is a difference between the two statements **only if** the temporary is not elided.

##### C++17

In C++17, there is [mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which means that in this case when we write:

```
std::string name = std::string("Eugene");
```

In the above statement, the language guarantees that

> No temporary on the right hand side is created. Instead, the object `name` is created directly using the string literal `"Eugene"` and a suitable `std::string`'s constructor.

So the answer to your question in C++17 is that there is **no difference** between the two statements.